# Univocity - Parse single row into multiple beans

Tags: univocity

Is it possible to parse a single line into multiple beans based on index ranges

**Example**:

Line: "field1", "field2", "field3", ...., "field9"

```
class ColumnsOneAndTwo {
   protected String field1;
   protected String field2;
}

class ColumnThreeAndNine {
   protected String field3;
   protected String field9;
}

class Row {

  @Parsed(indexes = 0, 1)
  protected ColumnOneAndTwo fields;

  @Parsed(indexes = 2, 8)
  protected ColumnThreeAndNine moreFields;

} 

BeanListProcessor<Row> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Row>(Row.class);

CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(parserSettings);

for (Row data : routines.iterate(Row.class, <file>, "UTF-8")) {  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `@Nested` annotation. Just use:

```
class ColumnsOneAndTwo {
    @Parsed(index=1)
    protected String field1;

    @Parsed(index=2)
    protected String field2;
}

class ColumnThreeAndNine {
    @Parsed(index=3)
    protected String field3;

    @Parsed(index=9)
    protected String field9;
}

class Row {

   @Nested
   protected ColumnOneAndTwo fields;

   @Nested
   protected ColumnThreeAndNine moreFields;

}
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)